# Configuration Exception when extending Sylius Admin User

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to install a newsletter bundle (https://github.com/ibrows/IbrowsNewsletterBundle) on my Symfony3-Sylius app (I didn't found Symfony3 newsletter bundle, so I try to install this one).
My App user must implements MandantUserInterface. Before that, I used Sylius default user system, so I have to override it to implement this interface.

I tried to override AdminUser, but I didn't found what model to override in my config.yml file ; I tried :

```
sylius_core:
        resources:
            admin_user:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\UserAdmin
```

But I saw that in the sylius_core config, I have not admin_user entry. I search for 'user' entry in configuration files, and the only one I found is

```
sylius_user:
    resources:
        user:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\UserAdmin
```

I saw this configuration in the Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php file. But if I put this conf in my config.yml file, I have this error :

```
Unrecognized option "classes" under "sylius_user.resources.user"
```

My question is : how to implement the `MandantUserInterface` in my User Object in order to user this newsletterBundle ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct conf is :

```
sylius_user:
    resources:
        admin:
          user:
              classes:
                  model: AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the same to extend the `AdminUser` with an two factor secret field.

Is it correct to also override the both parameters like this in config.yml?

```
parameters:

  sylius.model.admin_user.class: AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser
  sylius.model.api_user.class: AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser
```